# How to change the values of a parameter within the domain in NDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, variable

In the following code, `e` is constant within the domain. But I want to change the value of `e` continuously within the domain. For instance, for 136 points in the `NDSolveValue`, I want 136 predetermined values of `e` and each value of `e` will be used in each point.

How can I implement this in the following code?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
e = 71;
T = 0;
alpha = 23.1*10^(-6);
row = 2.7;
rpm = 150.0;
wom = (2.0*\[Pi]*rpm)/60;
new = 0.3;
x = NDSolveValue[{(-F[r] + 
      r (Derivative[1][F][r] + 
         r ((3 + new) r row wom^2 + 
            alpha e T + (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])))/(e r) == 0, 
    F[15] == 0, F[150] == 0}, F, {r, 15, 150}];
```

Comment: One way to implement it is to define `e=Interpolation[pts]`, where `pts` is an array of data points.  Then, change `e` to `e[r]` two places in the DE.

Comment: @LouisB Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
T = 0;
alpha = 231*10^(-7);
row = 27/10;
rpm = 150;
wom = (2*π*rpm)/60;
new = 3/10;

x = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(-F[r] +
        r (F'[r] + r ((3 + new) r row wom^2 + alpha e T + F''[r])))/
      (e r) == 0, F[15] == 0, F[150] == 0}, F, {r, 15, 150}, {e}];
```

Plotting,

```
Plot[x[71][r], {r, 15, 150}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[x[e][r], {r, 15, 150}, {e, 0, 200}]
```

[image]

Comment: I reckon `ParametricNDSolveValue` solves the equation within the domain with a fixed value of `e` but my target was to put different values of `e` in each nodal point during the calculation. Therefore, the technique given by @LouisB may be the solution to my problem.